# Show choice points when unsatisfiable

Tags: minizinc

When running programs in MiniZinc, the -s flag lets me see the number of choice points explored while looking for a solution. However, if the conditions are unsatisfiable, the number of choice points explored is not shown.

How can I show choice points even if the conditions are unsatisfiable?

Comment: I don't think any FlatZinc solver has this feature. (And I'm not sure what this would mean: If a model is not satisfiable are there any choices to report?)

Comment: @hakank I'm very new to MiniZinc (only a few days in fact), but my understanding was that choice points were the number of options explored before a solution was found. So if there isn't a solution that satisfies the conditions, shouldn't MiniZinc at least say how many options were explored? Again, I may be totally wrong in this.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Some FlatZinc solvers might show statistics (when using the -s flag) even for unsatisfiable models, but some don't. And sometimes the first flattening process may give UNSATISFIABLE ("Warning: model inconsistency detected") without any statistics. So it seems to depend on the solver and how the UNSAT was reached.

Comment: @hakank Alright. I think this is as far as my question's gonna get answered.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fzn-gecode` you could visualize the search tree by using their Gist functionality. A lot of documentation about gist can be found in [Gecode's Modeling Guide](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/MPG.pdf). It does however assume that you're writing C++ code.

To use it from a MiniZinc model, execute the following commands:

1. `mzn2fzn -G gecode [model].mzn (data.dzn)`
2. `fzn-gecode -mode gist [model].fzn`